# Creating Dynamic properties for object

Tags: c#, dynamic-properties

I have a problem in creating dynamic objects. Please find the below code,

```
List<object> membersList = new List<object>();
foreach(var members in activityMembers){
    dynamic myObject = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    myObject.MemberNumber = members.MemberNumber;
    myObject.MemberName = members.Name;
    foreach (var activity in members.ActivityList)
    {
        myObject.[activity.ActivityName] = activity.Minutes;
    }
    membersList.Add(myObject);
}
```

there inside the second foreach loop, i need to generate the properties to all activities. for example if there are 4 activities in members.ActivityList, then 4 properties needs to be generated for object.

```
myObject.Activity1 = 10;
myObject.Activity2 = 20;
myObject.Activity3 = 30;
myObject.Activity4 = 40;
```

How can i do this? What i did wrong here?

Regards,
Karthik.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `.` when you are indexing the object i.e. change

```
myObject.[activity.ActivityName] = activityMinutes;
```

to

```
myObject[activity.ActivityName] = activity.Minutes;
```

---

Actually this won't solve your problem straight away, it will compile fine but when you attempt to run it will throw a `RuntimeBinderException` as you can't index into a `ExpandoObject` directly. You need to cast it as a dictionary before iterating (that's effectively what it is) e.g.

```
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)myObject;
...
dict[activity.ActivityName] = activity.Minutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to treat the `ExpandoObject` as a dictionary for that part:

```
IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = myObject;
foreach (var activity in members.ActivityList)
{
    dictionary[activity.ActivityName] = activity.Minutes;
}
```

That's the way of assigning properties to an `ExpandoObject` when you *don't* know the property name at compile-time.